# Constraints for mechanical linkage -- linear to rotational

Tags: animation, constraints, drivers

I'm trying to model a mechanical linkage using constraints and drivers (not rigging). In particular, I have a shaft (orange) that travels linearly, and it drives a pinion gear (purple) to rotate.

I've looked into using the Transformation object constraint, but it has problems. One is that shaft location value is local even when I use world space for the target. The setup looks like the following:

[image]

When the *driver* disk rotates, it moves the *arm*, and the *arm* pushes/pulls the *shaft* up and down. The *pinion-1* disk should rotate as though it were a gear and the shaft were a rack.

I used empties to help control where the *arm* attaches to the *driver* and the *arm* attaches to the *shaft*. I use Limit Distance and Limit Location to make sure the *shaft* moves up/down with the *arm*.

This shows the driver in a different position.

[image]

I attached the blend file. In the file, I'm using a driver for the z-rotation of the pinion. It works, but I'd prefer a better solution.

[image]

Comment: The more serious problem is that arm disconnects from shaft, because the serial constraints aren't actually what this demands-- the position of shaft's origin needs to lie on the intersection of a line and a circle that is centered on the origin of arm.  This is not something that Blender is good at, and the best way to handle it is to use drivers and look up how to figure out that intersection in some geometry (math) sources.

Comment: Thanks for diagnosing this, but I'm not clear. The positions are determined by two empties, *driver-arm-attachment* and  *arm-pinion-attachment*. The *arm-pinion-attachment* has a Limit Distance constraint to keep it a fixed distance away from the other empty. The *arm* has a Copy Location constraint to keep its origin on the first empty, and a Track To constraint so that it aligns towards the second empty. It looks to me like it "disconnects" a little because the Limit Distance constraint distance is a little bit longer than the length of *arm*. Is this a problem? Is there a better way?

Comment: It's only a problem if you or your client don't like the render-- you probably won't be able to say until you have your actual geometry.  The issue is with the two *serial* constraints on arm-pinion-attachment, which are simulating where it should be, but cannot get it exactly right.  (For your explicit question: While transformation constraint *can* rotate pinon-1, a driver like you have is probably preferable-- I would call the driver solution the best solution.)

Comment: Again, thanks for explaining. I'm working on solution that uses drivers instead of the serial constraints. I'll post the solution when I sort out the messy math.

Comment: I implemented a python solution that computes both the shaft z-position and the arm rotation angle. The details are in an external python file (so the python can be registered and be accessible as driver function). Basically: arm rotation = acos(driver_pivot_len/arm_len*sin(driver_rot)) and shaft_z = driver_pivot_len*cos(driver_rot)+arm_len*sin(arm_rot)

I'll share the python if anyone requests it.